# Phalcon Volt turns html code into string

Tags: html, phalcon, volt

I have html code from my db and I'm trying to print it as `{{ blog.content }}`. But it renders as string and shows all the html tags etc. How can I make it to render as html?

it looks like:

```
<p>I am writing my blog post here to show everyone that I can do such things as this: <span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Impact; font-size: 36px;">adsdsfadsf&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 11px; background-color: yellow;">and also like this one</span></p>
```

htmltags shouldn't be visible. The line above should be rendered as html. Which means bold parts example; should be bold.

Comment: Could you add an example please?

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump(blog)`?

Comment: @JamesFenwick, it's in volt. How can I var_dump it?

Comment: {{dump(blog}} or temporarily remove the volt file and var_dump from the controller

Comment: Sorry, I can't share all the dump because it is an object directly from db. but my blog.content dump is like this:  

string(330) "<p>I am writing my blog post here to show everyone that I can do such things as this: <span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Impact; font-size: 36px;">adsdsfadsf&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 11px; background-color: yellow;">and also like this one</span></p>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create Elements.php (Library or Plugin all are same)

```
namespace YourAppNameSpace;

use Phalcon\Config;

class Elements extends \Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin
{
     public function decodeString($string)
    {
        return html_entity_decode($string);
    }
}
```

2) Add Elements.php to the service

```
$di->set('element', function () {
    return new YourAppNameSpace\Elements();
});
```

3) In Volt File Try this

```
{{ element.decodeString(blog.content) }}
```

Hope It Works.. :)

Comment: I've added the function my existing helper. Thanks!